# Importing modules, when several (sub-)folders have same names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-import

When the project directory and a subfolder has the same name, I get an import error when running pytest.

I have tried to rename the subfolder and then there is no problem.

For example with the following folder structure:

- project/

  - project/

    - tools.py
  - foo/

    - foofile.py
  - bar/
  - unittest/

    - test_foofile.py

In project/foo/foofile.py we try to import classes from project/project/tools.py:

```py
from project.tools import ClassA
```

When then running `python -m pytest` from the first level directory project/ i get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassA' from 'project.tools' (unknown location)

Is there a way to say to the interpreter that it should look into the subfolder project?

Comment: Have you tried `from project.project.tools import ClassA`?

Comment: Have you verified that your current working directory is the inner `project` folder, while also ensuring the outer one is not find-able by the normal import machinery ?

Comment: @Post169: That is not an option since the project is used as a submodule in other projects. Then the directory name cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: It looks like you want to import from an absolute path. Here's a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: It's depend on sevral things :

When you run pytest command, in wich folder are you ?
Have you put an __init__.py file in each subfolders ?

Comment: The working directory is the outer project folder. The `__init__.py` is empty.